# AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute '_BACKEND'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, rasa-nlu, rasa

I am following a book on building chat bots and continue running into this error when attempting to start interactive learning.

The full error is this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "train_initialize.py", line 18, in 
>       agent = Agent("horoscope_domain.yml", policies = [MemoizationPolicy(), KerasPolicy()])
>     File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\policies\keras_policy.py", line 31, in **init**
>       if KerasPolicy.is_using_tensorflow() and not graph:
>     File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\policies\keras_policy.py", line 48, in is_using_tensorflow
>       return keras.backend._BACKEND == "tensorflow"
>   AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute '_BACKEND'

my code looks like this 
'''

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from rasa_core import utils
import tensorflow.keras.backend
from rasa_core.agent import Agent
from rasa_core.policies.keras_policy import KerasPolicy
from rasa_core.policies.memoization import MemoizationPolicy
from rasa_core.policies.sklearn_policy import SklearnPolicy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    utils.configure_colored_logging(loglevel="DEBUG")

    training_data_file = './data/stories.md'
    model_path = './models/dialogue'
    agent = Agent("horoscope_domain.yml", policies = [MemoizationPolicy(), KerasPolicy()])

    training_data = agent.load_data(training_data_file)

    agent.train(training_data, augmentation_factor = 50, epochs = 500, batch_size = 10, validation_split = 0.2)
    agent.persist(model_path)
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like outdated API code; open the files in the error trace, and replace `._BACKEND` w/ `.backend()`:

```py
# In "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages
# \rasa_core\policies\keras_policy.py", line 48:

# return keras.backend._BACKEND == "tensorflow" # <-- DELETE
return keras.backend.backend() == "tensorflow"  # <-- PASTE
```

Comment: That worked, now i'm getting this error though  ** Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_initialize.py", line 18, in <module>
    agent = Agent("horoscope_domain.yml", policies = [MemoizationPolicy(), KerasPolicy()])
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\policies\keras_policy.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.graph = keras.backend.tf.get_default_graph()
AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'tf' **

Comment: @Max_Meadowcroft Whatever this "rasa" API you're using is, I suggest using something else - it appears ridden with bugs. Notify its creator of these issues - and I doubt they'll be stopping here. The question, as originally asked, is resolved - you can ask a new one if need be. But due to the error's simplicity, I'll answer regardless: remove `keras.backend.` entirely from the line of code in the error trace - it should just be `tf.get_default_graph()`

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Can you please take a look into this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/58900947/5904928
I am struggling for hours, couldn't find an answer.